# Existence of vector $w\in\mathbb{C}^n$ so that $Qw=(f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n))$ for RKHS

Tags: reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Suppose I have a RKHS $\mathcal{H}$ on a set $X$ with kernel $K$. Moreover, othere are $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\subset X$ distinct points. We denote by $Q=(K(x_i,x_j))\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. In *An Introduction to the Theory of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces, by V.I. Paulsen and M. Raghupathi* they say for each $f\in\mathcal{H}$ there is a vector $w\in\mathbb{C}^n$ such that

$$Qw = (f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n)) $$

How can this conclusion be drawn? I was trying to work with the reproducing kernel property but didn't manage to get.

$$f(x_i) = \langle f, K(\cdot, x_i)\rangle $$

and trying to invoke the adjoint, without any success. Any hint / help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $k_i(x):=K(x,x_i)$ for $i=j,\ldots,n$. Project $\bar f\in\mathscr{H}$ orthogonally onto the span of the $k_i$ to obtain
$$ \bar f=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i k_i + g$$
for suitable $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{C}$ and a $g\in\mathscr{H}$ orthogonal to the span. Now for all $i=1,\ldots,n$
$$ \bar f(x_j)=\langle \bar f,k_j\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \langle k_i, k_j\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i K_{ji}$$
where we used the fact that $\langle g, k_j\rangle=0$ due to orthogonality.

With $v=\big(f(x_1),\ldots, f(x_n)\big)$, $w=\bar \alpha$ and $\bar Q=K(x_j,x_i)$ this is
$$ \bar v_j = \big( \bar Q\alpha\big)_j$$
or $$ v=Qw.$$

Comment: thanks for the comment. I totally agree that your mentioned Theorem 3.4 allows this. However, check Theorem 3.8, I quote: "Let \mathcal{H} be an RKHS on $X$ with Kernel K, $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\subset X$ be a finite set of distinct points, let $v=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $Q=(K(x_i,x_j))$. Then there exists a vector $w=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ s.t. $(v-Qw)\in\mathcal{N}(Q)$ \dots". There is no mentioning of the range of $Q$ or invertible $K$.

Comment: Yes, you are right I was a bit quick and did not find this respective citation. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you share a resource why this is true: "Note that Q is a symmetric, square matrix. This means Rn is the direct sum of R the range of Q and N its null space. "

Comment: The point which still puzzles me is that it seems to imply that $Q$ is surjective, isn't it? That would mean every symmetric positive semi-definite matrix is surjective

Comment: This is what confused me in the beginning as well! But notice that you only demand that  $(f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n))$ is in the range of $Q$ not all vectors. Take as extreme example $K=0$ such that $Q=0$. Then $Q$ is definitely not surjective but the statement still holds, since the only $f\in\mathscr{H}$ is the zero function. But you are right I should give arguments that $r=(f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n))$.

Comment: @swissy: See my revised approach. This should now be complete.

Comment: Many thanks for the additional detail!